# Difference between installing new Windows 10 versions via Windows Update vs. DVD

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-installation

What is the difference between updating to a new [version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history) of Windows 10 (such as the recently released version 1607) via Windows Update compared with running `Setup.exe` from a DVD or ISO image with the installer for the latest Windows version?

I'm interested in knowing what technically happens behind the scenes, as well as practical differences like installation time, reliability, and residual effects.

Comment: FWIW, this question was prompted by [difficulties](http://superuser.com/q/1111158/54568) installing Windows 10 Version 1607.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference at all.

The Windows 10 1607 update (just like the 1511 update before it) downloads and unpacks all the same files that are found on the .ISO and then initiates the process the same way.

The "update" is not really an update, it's an entire OS upgrade no matter how you acquire it.